# C# generate the Next sequence of alphanumeric string

Tags: c#, string

I want to generate the `Next` sequence of *alphanumeric string* in C# windows application. check `max` number and generate the Next sequence

eg-

```
  A10100001 => A10100002 => A10100003 => A10100004 ...... A10100999 => A10101001

  ABC000001 => ABC000002 => ABC000003 => ABC000004 ...... ABC000999 => ABC001001
```

please help me i am new to programming...

Comment: Please show what have you tried and what isn't working with it

Answer (score 3):

Try *regular expression* to extract the last number (which we have to increment):

```
private static string Next(string value) {
  string number = Regex.Match(value, "[0-9]+$").Value;

  return value.Substring(0, value.Length - number.Length) + 
         (long.Parse(number) + 1).ToString().PadLeft(number.Length, '0');
}
```

Or `Regex.Replace` version which is *terser*, but less *readable*:

```
private static string Next(string value) {
  return Regex.Replace(value, "[0-9]+$", 
    match => (long.Parse(match.Value) + 1).ToString($"D{match.Length}"));
}
```

Test:

```
// "abc0046"
Console.Write(Next("abc0045"));
// "abc0045xyz124" (please, notice, that it's the last 123 which is incremented)
Console.Write(Next("abc0045xyz123"));
```

In case you have a *sequence* of items with *same pattern* you can use *Linq*:

```
 string[] items = new string[] { "ABC001", "ABC105", "ABC024" };  

 // "ABC106"
 Console.Write(Next(items.Max()));
```

Comment: for "AABC001Z99"  I was expecting "AABC002A00", but got something unexpected "AABC001Z100"  :( any help?

Comment: In my code I increment the last number (99) only (and so we have 100). You, probably want to add 1 to 36-base (0..9A..Z) number which is a different problem

Answer (score 0):

1. Find the first digit in the string
2. Split it
3. parse second part to integer
4. increment
5. Concatenate